# JBPM core engine , Using mysql instead of H2 database

Tags: mysql, maven, jbpm

In our project i am using JBPM core only. We have a maven project setup instead of ANT. 
I am trying to use JBPM with mysql instead of H2 database . 
I tried multiple blog posts and JBOSS documentation but everything is explained based on whole JBPM stack and with ANT profiler.

Can anyone help me in integrating JBPM core with mysql database with maven.

Comment: you should give some more information... can you post your pom.xml?

Comment: in my pom i have included this dependency :                                                 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
      <artifactId>jbpm</artifactId>
      <version>6.3.0.Final</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

Comment: What about the environment? What's your application server?

Comment: we are working on drop-wizard application so , jetty